# force www in htaccess by merging with another rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, fuelphp

I'm trying to force www on my website using a RewriteRule in the htaccess file.

I'm using FuelPHP and I have to have the following rewrite rule in the htaccess file but the methods I found to force www didn't play nice with my current setup.

Current htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Code that I found here to force www

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

How can I combine these to enable forcing www and still have the other rule in the htacess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Redirect to wwww
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.yourdomain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: You might want an [NC] after `%{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.yourdomain\.com` so it's case insensitive. Just in case.

Answer (score 0):

FuelPHP comes with a .htaccess file in the public folder that contains a rewrite example for this situation.